# Search in Json from URL

Tags: json, react-native

I have an URL from which I fetch json data, which has many objects within it. I want to access a specific data in a specific object in that json data. 
How can I.?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: actually, I'm new to react native. so I didn't know how

Comment: you need to try to have it done first by yourself, and next when you've faced with a `specific` question, you can ask here for help (of course you need to search before if this question was asked/answered before. Now your question is too broad, and there too many of possible solutions. [Maybe it was answered already?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+get+json+value)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using fetch, you can get the data like this:

```
fetch('yourUrl', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers:
    {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
.then(async (response) =>
{
    const   json = await response.json();
    if (json)
        console.log(json.YOUR_OBJECT_KEY);
    return (json);
})
.catch(err => console.warn(err.message))
```

So, withing the then, we are decrypting the response, (`response.json()`) and we are getting all the information.
Depending of the json file you fetched, you can access an element by doing the `json.YOUR_OBJECT_KEY` (here, json is basically your json converted to be usable by JS, and YOUR_OBJECT_KEY is, well, your object key)